How to run a bash script at login in Ubuntu 24.04
How to run script at login in Ubuntu 24.04
In this case, I use xscreensaver, on the xorg desktop and everything works fine, but there is no way to log in, in activated mode with: xscreensaver --nosplash. I have already tried with:
gnome-session-properties

and also with the function:
sudo cp "yourscriptname" /etc/init.d && sudo update-rc.d "yourscriptname" defaults

None of these worked.

If you want to run your script on login, you can add the script file to the "Startup Applications"

Did not work I already try with "gnome-session-properties"  and nothing happens. The only way is with "gnome-tweaks" and the option is "XscreenSaver Settings". No the function for just "activated" which would be: "xscreensaver --nosplash" . Thanks for answer, greetings
